# How do you express a "generous grader"?

Tags: word-choice

I am wondering how to express a teacher/instructor who is generous in their grading.
For example "He is a generous grader. Don't worry too much in his class."

In Chinese, some have said I can use "宽松" to describe a lenient teacher. （The antonym for “严肃” / serious)

However, I am unsure if this is correct for this scenario.

For example, “他评分很宽松。上他的课不必太担心”

Comment: Note: It's possible to [edit] question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antonym for  宽松 (loose) is 严格 (strict) when it comes to grading

> However, I am unsure if this is correct for this scenario.

> For example, “他评分很宽松。上他的课不必太担心”

Using 宽松(loose) is perfect in this scenario. When a teacher grades to a loose standard, he would accept  unprecise answers that would be deemed wrong by a stricter grader

Answer (score 2):

She's a generous grader.
她是个慷慨的计分者.
Don't worry too much in her class.
在她的课堂上不要太担心.

Answer (score 2):

寬鬆的改卷員

改卷員: somebody who grades test and exam papers